# Can I setup IntelliSense suggestions which depend on another property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, intellisense

Okay this is probably a naive question but I want to get IntelliSense suggestions on a property for multiple enums. Well. Kinda. But let me explain.

I got a couple of enums like so

```
public static class Icons 
{
    public enum Regular { /* ... */ }
    public enum Solid{ /* ... */ }
    public enum Brands { /* ... */ }
}

public enum Styles { /* ... */ }
```

Now I got a XAML Control with two DependencyProperties

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyStyle), typeof(Styles), typeof(Icon), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Styles.None, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnUpdateControl));

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyIconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyIcon), typeof(object), typeof(Icon), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnUpdateControl));
```

`Control.Style` accepts values from the enum `Styles`.
`Control.Icon` accepts values `Icons.[Regular, Solid, Brands]`.

The IntelliSense suggestions for `Icon` depends on the selected `Style`. So if `Control.Style` is `Styles.Regular` then show only suggestions for `Icons.Regular` on `Control.Icon`.

Comment: Don't use enums.  Use a type hierarchy.

Comment: @Mitch can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

It is theoretically possible to add a [`CompletionProvider`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/15974#issuecomment-268297743) that would permit Intellisense to handle your single class, but that would be overkill for such a common issue.  Instead, use an enum class or use category classes.

Enum class (not quite, since the constructor is public, but in this case having it open seems logical):

```
public sealed class IconImage
{
    public Uri ImageUri { get; }
    public IconImage(Uri imageUri)
    {
        this.ImageUri = imageUri;
    }

    public static class ApplicationActions
    {
        public readonly IconImage Save = new IconImage(new Uri("foo"));
        public readonly IconImage Open = new IconImage(new Uri("foo"));
        public readonly IconImage Print = new IconImage(new Uri("foo"));
    }

    public static class Marks
    {
        public readonly IconImage Check = new IconImage(new Uri("foo"));
        public readonly IconImage Tickbox = new IconImage(new Uri("foo"));
        public readonly IconImage CheckedTickbox = new IconImage(new Uri("foo"));
    }

    // ...
}

// Usage: control.Icon = IconImage.Marks.TickBox;
// XAML (without TypeConverter): Icon="{x:Static local:IconImage.Marks.TickBox}"
// XAML (with TypeConverter): Icon="Marks.TickBox"
```

Category Classes:

```
public enum IconImage
{
    Save, Open, Print,
    Check, Tickbox, CheckedTickbox,
    // ...
}

public static class IconImages
{
    public static class Application
    {
        public static readonly IconImage
            Save = IconImage.Save,
            Open = IconImage.Open,
            Print = IconImage.Print;
    }

    public static class Marks
    {
        public static readonly IconImage
            Check = IconImage.Check,
            Tickbox = IconImage.Tickbox,
            CheckedTickbox = IconImage.CheckedTickbox;
    }

    // … other category classes …
}

// Usage: control.Icon = IconImage.Print  -- or --  control.Icon = IconImages.Application.Print
// XAML: Icon="Print" -- or -- Icon="{x:Static local:IconImages.Application.Print}"
```

With either route, I would suggest using a tool like T4 or XSLT to dynamically generate the code.  It is very easy to introduce bugs when trying to maintain large lists manually.